# proxy setting and unsetting in java

Tags: java, proxy

So I have to fire a URL which needs proxy. This URL then redirects to another URL which doesn't require proxy(localhost). I Set the proxy by doing the following:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxyHost) ;  
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort",proxyPort) ;
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",proxyHost) ; 
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort",proxyPort) ;
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");
```

The redirect URL is not reaching my server(localhost).
However, If I run the URL on the browser, it is redirecting to my server as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [URL.openConnection(proxy)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28java.net.Proxy%29) instead.

With that API, you can control the proxy settings for each individual connection.

Comment: Seems like its not the proxy problem. I have posted almost the entire code here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113744/internal-server-error-500-when-i-try-to-automate-login-to-facebook-in-java). Any suggestions?