# Internal server Error 500 when I try to automate login to facebook in java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, automation

I am largely following this :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

I am able to get the form details. I even constructed the params. Then when I post the request, I get internal server error 500!

Whats wrong ? here is my code :

```
public class Abc {
private List<String> cookies;
private HttpsURLConnection conn;
private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
 String proxyHost="43.88.65.10";
 String proxyPort="8080";

    System.out.println("Setting proxy....");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxyHost) ;  

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",proxyHost) ;  
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort",proxyPort) ;
    System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1|43.88.102.142");
    System.setProperty("https.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1|43.88.102.142");
    System.out.println("Proxy Set.");

    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9091&scope=read_stream";

    String fb = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3F&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9091/test&scope=publish_stream&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&ret=login";

     Abc tryObject = new Abc();

     CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
        String page = null;
        try {
            page = tryObject.GetPageContent(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String postParams = null;
        try {
            postParams = tryObject.getFormParams(page, "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("postParams"+postParams);

        //postParams = "lsd=AVoao3Js&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&display=page&enable_profile_selector=&legacy_return=1&profile_selector_ids=&skip_api_login=1&signed_next=1&trynum=1&timezone=&lgnrnd=044127_BBYN&lgnjs=n&email=XXXXXXXXXXX%40gmail.com&pass=XXXXXXXX&persistent=1&default_persistent=0&login=Log+In";


        // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
        // authentication
        //tryObject.sendPost(url, postParams);
        try {
            tryObject.sendPost(fb, postParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }//end of main




  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // default is GET
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // act like a browser
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            }
        }
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // Get the response cookies
        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

        return response.toString();

      }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
        this.cookies = cookies;
      }


  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        System.out.println("doc-->"+doc);

        //FB form id
        Element loginform = doc.getElementById("loginform");
        Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
        List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            String value = inputElement.attr("value");

            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Email"))
                value = username;
            else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Pass"))
                value = password;
            paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }

        // build parameters list
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String param : paramList) {
            if (result.length() == 0) {
                result.append(param);
            } else {
                result.append("&" + param);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
      }


  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // Acts like a browser
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.facebook.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.facebook.com/");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        System.out.println("Length-->"+postParams.length());

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();




        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = 
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
         System.out.println(response.toString());
```

}
}

The error I get is 
Response Code : 500
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3F&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9091/test&scope=publish_stream&client_id=XXXXXXXXXX&ret=login
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at facebook.Abc.sendPost(Abc.java:216)
    at facebook.Abc.main(Abc.java:78)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3F&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9091/test&scope=publish_stream&client_id=XXXXXXXXX&ret=login
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at facebook.Abc.sendPost(Abc.java:210)
    ... 1 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting most of the code below so that it can help others(a big thanku to MKYONG :) )

```
public class FbLogin {
private List<String> cookies;


private HttpURLConnection conn;

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
private final String PROXY_HOST = "XXXXXXX";
private final String PROXY_PORT = "80";
private final String charset = "UTF-8";
private final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8000/";
boolean redirect = false;

private void setProxy(){
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", PROXY_HOST);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", PROXY_HOST);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT);
}
public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
}

public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    String USERNAME = "XXXXX@gmail.com";
    String PASSWORD = "XXXXXX";

    FbLogin httpd = new FbLogin();
    httpd.setProxy();
    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    String page = "";
    try {
        page = httpd.sendGet();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    String postParams = "";
    try {
        postParams = httpd.getFormsParams(page, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        httpd.sendPost(postParams);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String sendGet()  {

    //Generating map for url path and query

    String loginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/v1.0/dialog/oauth";
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> queryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    queryMap.put("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI);
    queryMap.put("scope", "read_stream");
    queryMap.put("client_id", "XXXXXXXXX");
    queryMap.put("ret", "login");

    //Creating URL with urlencoder
    String fbUrlString = generateUrl(loginUrl, queryMap);

    System.out.println("Generated Url ---> " + fbUrlString);
    URL myFbURL = null;
    try {
        myFbURL = new URL(fbUrlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFbURL.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //optional -default is GET
    try {
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //add request headers
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    //Normally 3xx response code is for redirect
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println( "Sending GET request to URL " + myFbURL);
    System.out.println( "Resonse code = " + responseCode);
    checkForRedirect(responseCode);
    return readPage();
}

private void sendPost(String postParams) throws Exception {

    String Url = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php";
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> queryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    queryMap.put("login_attempt", "1");
    queryMap.put("next", "https://www.facebook.com/v1.0/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F&scope=read_stream&client_id=XXXXXXXX&ret=login");
    //Creating URL with urlencoder
    String postUrl = generateUrl(Url, queryMap);
    System.out.println( "Generated Url ---> " + postUrl);

    URL obj = new URL(postUrl);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    //         for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
    //             conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    //         }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + postUrl);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    checkForRedirect(responseCode);
    readPage();
}

private String getFormsParams(String html, String username, String password)
throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println( "Extracting forms data");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    //Facebook form
    Element loginForm = doc.getElementById("login_form");
    Elements inputElements = loginForm.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Element inputElement : inputElements ) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");
        System.out.println("key --> " + key);
        System.out.println("value --> " + value);

        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("email")){
            value = username;
        }
        else if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("pass")){
            value = password;
        }
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

    //build parameter list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(String param : paramList) {
        if(result.length() == 0){
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private String readPage(){
    BufferedReader buffReader = null;
    try {
        buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        while ((inputLine = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        buffReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response.toString();
}
private void redirectHandler(){
    //If redirect is true launch the new redirected url
    if(redirect) {
        // get redirect url from "location" header field
        String newURL = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

        // get the cookie if need, for login
        String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newURL).openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //          conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies)
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");


        System.out.println( "Redirecting to " + conn.getURL());
        try {
            System.out.println( "Resonse code = " + conn.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            checkForRedirect(conn.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
private void checkForRedirect(int responseCode){
    if(responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
        || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
            redirect = true;
            redirectHandler();
        }
    }
}


private String generateUrl(String url, LinkedHashMap<String, String> queryMap) {
    System.out.println( "Inside generateUrl method ...");
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    char separator = '?';

    for(Entry<String, String> entry : queryMap.entrySet()) {
        query.append(separator);
        separator = '&'     ;   
        try {
            query.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), charset));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        query.append("=");
        try {
            query.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), charset));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    url = url + query;
    return url;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Internal Server Error 500" means your code made the server crash. There is some bug in your code.

Comment: Fb is supposed to return a code to me. So I have a server running on my machine. BTW,I tried redirect url as graph.facebook.com and https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html but still getting same error. my colleague was able to do the same using python! redirect url was localhost!

Comment: You're right; the `localhost` is interpreted by your browser and not the server, so that should work. I removed this part of my answer. My original comment still holds: There must be something wrong with one of the parameters that you send to facebook. Compare each of them with the Python version and eliminate each difference that you encounter, no matter how unimportant it may seem.